# Debugging: finding a JS variable/object based on its value

Tags: firebug, javascript

I have a huge JS library (three.js). (This library loads and displays a .jpg image as texture on the html5 canvas.)
I'm looking for the object in the code that contains the loaded image **data** itself. I know that the loaded image data contains following text in the .jpg head section: "Adobe Photoshop CS4".

What should I do to find this object or the variable itself that contains this text?

Do you guys know a debugging program or plugin or something else that could find an object or a variable based on its value?

Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a loop and check all the variables on the page.
You have to search the window as a tree.

```
function search(x){
    try{
        for(i in x){
            if(x[i]=="Adobe Photoshop CS4"){
                alert("found");
            }else{
                search(x[i]);
            }
        }   
    }catch(e){}
    return;
}
search(window);
```

You need a good pc to run the code.